# How to refer to a column in a excel with something like Cells("Name").Value instead of Cells(n,m) in vbscript?

Tags: excel, vbscript

I have an excel with predefined column headers.The problem is these column headers can be at any position for every iteration that is  only column headers are fixed not their position(index). So, I need to get the column index based on the column name for further processing.

Comment: Use MATCH for the header label in row(1:1) to get the numerical column position.

Comment: In vbscript, or VBA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found another way to access the column as described in the question, so I though I should change my first answer accordingly. But I thought maybe that answer works for other cases.

Here is a quicker way to get hold of a column containing the value:

```
Sub Macro1()

    ColumnByValue("age").Offset(5, 0).Value = "17"

End Sub

Function ColumnByValue(col As String) As Range

   Set ColumnByValue = Range("1:1").Find(col)

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.Find()` to locate the cell containing the column you are looking for.
I wrote the following example to add a value at a certain column, on a specified row number. You might want to change the code so that it adds the value to the bottom of the existing values instead. For simplicity, the code below will find the column, go down to the specified row and change the value to the value specified by the caller.

```vb
Sub Macro1()

   Dim result As Boolean
   result = add_value_to_column("age", atRow:=3, newValue:=17)

   'was that successful? 
   If result = True Then
       MsgBox "value was added"
   Else
       MsgBox "value NOT added. maybe column does not exist"
   End If


End Sub
```

---

```
Function add_value_to_column(col_name As String, _
                             atRow As Integer, _
                             newValue As String) As Boolean    

   Dim c As Range

   'Assuming the header row is the first row at the top (1:1)
   With Range("1:1")

       'try to find the column specified in the function parameters
       Set c = .Find(col_name, LookIn:=xlValues)

       'If the column was found then it will not be nothing
       'NOT NOTHING = THING :)

       If Not c Is Nothing Then
           'access the row specified in the parameter, at the column,
           'and set the value for that location

           Cells(atRow, c.Column).Value = newValue

           'Optioal: inform the caller that the value was set
           add_value_to_column = True
       Else
           'optional: inform the caller that column was not found
           add_value_to_column = False
       End If
   End With

End Function
```

Here is an image showing a sample data set. Running the code above has added the value `17` to the `age` column for the row number `3`

[image: Example of the .find function]